# How to guess whether $X>Y$ or $X<Y$ from $X$ or $Y$ when the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is unknown

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Somebody chooses two real random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and writes them on two
>   sheets of paper. The distribution of the pair $(X,Y)$ is unknown to you, but you do know that $P(X=Y)=0$. You toss a fair coin (the toss is of course independent of $(X,Y)$) to choose one of
>   the sheets, which is then handed to you, so that you see the number on it. Call this random number $W$ and the other number, still unknown to you, $Z$. Your task is to guess whether $W$ is bigger than $Z$ or not. You can generate independent Uniform$([0,1])$ random variables at will, so your strategy could be random.
>
> a) Show that if your guess is always that $W>Z,$ then the probability of being correct is exactly $1/2$.
>
> b) Exhibit a strategy for which the probability of being correct is $1/2+\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon >0.$
>
> c) Assume that you know that $X$ and $Y$ will be chosen among integers from 0 to 5. Find, with proof, the largest $\epsilon$ that works for all such distributions.

I know how to do a) and b). I am incredibly confused how to do c) and I have no idea. I will write out my solutions to a) and b) and I hope that somebody can help me with c).

> Solution to a):
>
> $$
> P(W>Z)=P(W=X, X>Y)+P(W=Y,Y>X)
> $$
>   $$
> P(W=X)P(X>Y)+P(W=Y)P(Y>X)=1/2\left( P(X>Y)+P(Y>X) \right)=1/2.
> $$

Now here is my solution to b).

> Solution to b):
>
> Let $G$ be an exponential random variable with expectation 1. You can obtain this as $-\log(U)$ where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Guess that $W>Z$ if $W>G$ and that $W<Z$ if $W<G$. Then we have that:
>   $$
> P(\text{guess correct})=P(W>Z,W>G)+P(W<Z,W<G)
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{1}{2}\left[P(X>Y,X>G)+P(Y>X,Y>G)+P(X<Y,X<G)+P(Y<X,Y<G)\right]
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{1}{2}\left[P(X>Y)+P(X>Y,Y<G<X)+P(X<Y)+P(X<Y,X<G<Y) \right]
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}P(G \text{ between } X \text{ and } Y).
> $$

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you choose $G$ randomly from $\{0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5\}$ with each being equally likely, and then guess that $W>Z$ if $W>G$ and that $W<Z$ if $W<G$?

Comment: @Henry, are you suggesting that this approach solves c)? If so I don't really see how we could prove such a thing.

Comment: I suspect that you can show that for any other distribution of $G$ with probabilities in the integer gaps not all equal to $\frac{1}{5}$, you could show that there is a distribution of $(X,Y)$ meeting the conditions which has a smaller $P(G \text{ between } X \text{ and } Y)$ than the $G$ I suggest.